# Why doesn't the readline while loop from HttpURLConnection block if HTTP protocol has no EOF character?

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to understand the logic of performing HTTP requests in Java using `HttpURLConnection` class (or `HttpsURLConnection` class). Here is my code to perform a GET request and print all response payload to stdout.

```java
URL url = new URI("https://swapi.dev/api/planets/1/");
String line;

HttpsURLConnection connection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream())
);

// read all data from response payload & print to screen
while ((line=input.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.println("All data retrieved!");
```

Here's the problem: this piece of codes worked fine, successfully read all the info and finished running! My question is, why isn't the execution eventually blocked at the `input.readLine()` part in the while loop?

When I did similar while-loop reading on TCP level, such a `readLine` will block until connection is closed from client side. According to the doc ([here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html)) of `HttpURLConnection` class, the underlying TCP connection is usually not closed for performance reason. So if I imagine `connection.getInputStream()` same as `socket.getInputStream()` in the TCP analogue, I'd expect the `input.readLine()` call to eventually block, too.

I guess this method might be overridden somewhere in the case of `HttpURLConnection` （maybe to make use of `Content-Length` header property?) However, I can't find this overridden anywhere.

Since I'm trying to dive as deep as possible, it would be great if you could help locate exactly how the `HttpURLConnection` class causes my while-loop to eventually end.

Comment: You seem to think that the end of the content of the response is somehow tied to the lifetime of the connection: it is not. The HTTP protocol specifies how and when a response is complete, and that is when the end of stream is reached for the response to the specific request. The TCP/IP connection itself may live longer for another request.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hi. Thanks for your info. Problem is, I don't remember HTTP protocol sends end of stream character at all. I remember that servers are recommended to use `Content-Length` header to know how many bytes to expect in the body, instead of waiting for EOS?

Comment: It doesn't send an 'end of stream character' as such, but you need to distinguish between the end of the transport mechanism (the connection), and the end of the response to the current HTTP request over that transport. The end of that response is handled either by Content-Length or the chunked transfer encoding, which signals the end of content in a specific way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why isn't the execution eventually blocked at the `input.readLine()` part in the while loop?

Because the `Reader.readLine()` call will return `null` when it reaches the end-of-stream on the input stream it is reading from.

It will reach the end-of-stream on the client side when the server side finishes sending the response data ... and the client has read it all.

The end-of-stream may or may not actually correspond to the server closing the TCP/IP connection.  It won't if HTTP [chunked transfer encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding) is being used for the HTTP connection.  Chunked encoding is used when the client and server agree to use a single connection for multiple request / responses.  The chunk headers will tell the client side when it has reached the end of a document ... and that it should signal end-of-stream on the input stream.

The `content-length` header may or may not come into this<sup>1</sup>.  But bear in mind that the server can send a response without a `content-length` header at all ... meaning that the client-side won't know ahead of time how much data to expect, and won't be able to use it for "framing" the response body.

For more details, refer to the RFCs that specify HTTP.  (This is better than looking at the client-side Java source code.  The client side code only tells you half of the story.)

---

<sup>1 - The HTTP specs say that if the server includes a `content-length` in the response headers, it must send exactly that number of bytes.  However, it doesn't mandate any specific client side behavior if the server sends less or more bytes than it said it would.</sup>

Comment: Thanks very much! I think chunked transfer encoding is exactly the piece I was missing.